# Firebase Google Indexing

Tags: ajax, firebase, indexing, google-search, google-index

I want to make a website based on frontend technologies. I would like to use Firebase as my DB. My website should be well indexed but I am not sure if it is possible with data retrieved from Firebase (they are loaded async). Is it possible to index your website relatively well, but still keep using Firebase database?

I have read a [google docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) about AJAX indexing, but it still required some server side coding.

Possible way is to serve my index.html (homepage) data from server, because I know, that website content will not be changed often. But I would like to avoid this one.

Comment: Google generally executes JavaScript when crawling sites nowadays. A site powered by the Firebase Realtime Database should be crawlable by Google. Other crawlers (e.g. Facebook OpenGraph, Twitter's cards) may not support JS execution.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thank you for reply! Do you now about that topic something more? I dont think it is so easy...

Comment: I am creating an app using Angular 4 and firebase firestore can someone help me in how to allow crawlers to crawl over my firebase database.

Comment: I think the best way is to use server side rendering.